# LARAVEL - Put my laravel project online in 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel

i already upload files in the public folder to public_html, and others to laravel.

i changed index.php too.

but i get nothing ....

[[image: What s[][1][1]]

[image]

[image]

I get this...
Some one can help me?
Thanks

EDIT:
This is my index file, i think thats is good

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

EDIT: 
Now i have this locally in XAMPP
[image]

Comment: ist test that locally working after making these changes of index file?

Comment: and can you show please index file?

Comment: check the edit pls

Comment: Are you saying split the project in Laravel and public folders locally, and see if it works?

Comment: Most likely, there is cast some sort of PHP Error which is not displayed due to server settings. Either check the log files if you have access to them, or put this at the top of your index.php file to enable printing errors: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: please try by replacing `require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';`  and next as  `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: @OleHaugset i put that, and dont give me anything....

Comment: @recoverymen i tried it too, nothing :S

Comment: dear ist try that is it working locally mean keep this whole public_html in your www or htdocs folder and check that is it working there or not...?

Comment: dont work locally, but i dont know why, i just copy the folder off projects, i have to install laravel in server? or something? i use artisan to run and runs...

Comment: @recoverymen, look at edit, how it looks now locally in XAMPP

Comment: sorry for late its error because you don't have .env file in that directory after placing env file generate app key run command as `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Thanks bro, now its almost working, just when i click in buttons, didn't redirect. Always says that object not found. But in artisan serve all routes working...

Comment: @recoverymen u see last comment?

Comment: glad if its working.

Comment: @recoverymen but routings is not working

Comment: all buttons stopped working?

Comment: @recoverymen routes didn't work, but if i put /myroute after link works....

Comment: Question, can you map the URL to a specific directory on your hosting server?? Is so then you don't need to put the contents of public in public_html separately, just simply upload the whole thing and just map the URL to your projects public directory like so "public_html/project_name/public".

Comment: Write down the errors?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old however others may find this answer useful. Basically what you have to do is to configure the App to work properly in the new environment.

1. Go to *000webhost cPanel > Settings > General > Reset website*. You must make sure no other content is present in your site to prevent interference.
2. Archive your entire Laravel Project in ZIP format.
3. Upload the archive to 000webhost site to `/public_html` using [File Manager](https://files.000webhost.com).
4. Move all files/folders which are on the same level with `package.json` to `/`
5. Delete `/public_html`. You won't need it anymore.
6. Rename `/public` to `/public_html`
7. Go to `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` at `register()` method and append the following code inside it:

   `$this -> app -> bind('path.public', function()`
   `{`
   `return base_path('public_html');`
   `});`
8. Open `/.env`. Copy `APP_KEY` value **without** `base64:`
9. Go to `/config/app.php`, find '`key`' and replace the line with the following code:

   `'key' => env('APP_KEY', base64_decode('%YOUR_COPIED_APPKEY%'));`
10. If you have your project connected to a database, update the database credentials from `/config/database.php`. Lookup for `mysql` vector and update the database, username, password properly.

...And this should do the trick. If you have further questions, a tutorial has been written about the entire procedure here: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey, please edit your answer to include sufficient detail to be useful even if the link goes dead, as they often eventually do.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am sorry, I am newbie. The correction is done.

Comment: I followed all steps shown above but still getting The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @MdSifatulIslam Post your issue in their forum: http://000webhost.com/forum

Answer (score 0):

WRITE YOUR index.php

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {

       return __DIR__ ; 

});
```

Comment: Check your PHP version