# Laravel run artisan commands on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I've host a website on http://000webhostapp.com
It was working fine since a while and it's showing me this error
"production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified"

I found out that I would have to run this artisan command

```
"php artisan key:generate"
```

to figure it out without downloading my files and run it on my machine. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just edit your .env file and update `APP_KEY=` to something like `base64:Gab61jKoEy3BldoePE6nTGLLjPve+9viG7yolLTW+Co=` (just ran it on my computer)

Answer (score 6):

in your route file.

```
Route::get('/key', function(){
     artisan::call('key:generate');
});
```

then run the route in your browser

But that won't work in [000webhost](http://000webhost.com)

Because *.env* is disabled for security reasons.
You will have to put the key in the *Config/app* file locate the line

```
'key' = env(APP_KEY);
```

Replace it with

```
'key' = 'your key'
```

Remember to add more necessary configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You should have SSH access for generating key, if not you can ask your hosting provider for running this command.

Comment: How? I don't know about shared hosting

Comment: You should look at your hosting panel for SSH Access

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful for someone,

Since **.env** is disabled for security reasons. You can generate a key in your local environment and put in your `config/app.php` like

```
'key' => env(APP_KEY, base64_decode('your-key-without-base64:'));
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917497/8677188) answer.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not a good way to run command on shared hosting as it can be
> risky, you should follow standard procee develop your project in local
> machine and then put it live on production.

Here is the link you can use to run basic command and you can configure further as per your requirement , [Snippet to run command on shared hosting](https://bitbucket.org/devdodiya/workspace/snippets/qna7AM)

As per this snippet all you have to do is to create 2 routes in your routing file and add logic to run command programatically as described here [laravel official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)