# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) On server

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, server

This is my .env code

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD="thismypass"
```

i have connected the database with the user with all privileges . But still get the error. i also tried reset the password and even create a new database and connect it with new user as well . Yet no success .

can you tell me what i can do next to solve my issue . i don't know why it says no password  even though i have password for my user.

thanks in advance

Comment: `root` is not `DB_USERNAME` - have you tried using MySQL Workbench first?

Comment: Also, why is your password in quotes here - but your username isn't?

Comment: It's also possible with quotes and without, e.g. you have special chars.

Comment: i also tried quotes with the username and database name but still same issue .

Comment: i do have special character in my password

Comment: try clearing and rebuilding config cache with `php artisan config:cache` command.

Comment: how do i run 'php artisan config:cache' in production server

Comment: @Yamin _Yegods_ You don't and you shouldn't. Don't you have a CI/CD system set-up?

Comment: Do you have CLI access?

Comment: no don't have cli access

Comment: i also upload the project in share hosting . does it have to do anything with the error ?

Comment: Laravel caches env values and other configurations. If you change env the changes are not immediately reflected due to the cache. you have to run `php artisan config:cache to reflect the changes immediately.

Comment: If you don't have CLI access, then you can run artisan commands with new routes. refer [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457478/6274211) answer. eg: `Route::get('/artisan/config-cache/clear', function(){
     artisan::call('config:cache');
});`

Comment: i tried that as well . but the error using password : no is still there

Comment: when i run the command config cache it show me 404 not found

Comment: Please check, do you have bootstrap/cache/config.php

Comment: yes i have bootstrap/cache/config.php