# Error in Laravel project installation on 000webhost.com

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I am new to installation of Laravel project. I followed the complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917497/10525759. The website starting opening but these are not the results which I require. The websites completely unorganized and images are also not displaying.

I an not able to find what's the problem with my website.

I am using 000webhost.com free hosting and inquired that this satisfy my project details.

I have php version 7.2. I have configured the database details correctly still getting the error. What's going wrong with my project?

Here is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:DVx0fmV7VHOPu2WX2GqZRfasCPDyzP6ZGveIsOBZXGQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id8541614_ecommerce
DB_USERNAME=id8541614_ecommerce
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_EMAIL_ID
MAIL_PASSWORD=UOUR_EMAIL_PASSOWRD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Check yours.env configuration

Comment: I think, the problem is caused by `strict MIME checking`. I'm searching now how to solve this problem

Comment: @AnkurTiwari i have edited the question and uploaded my env file, can you please tell me whats going wrong

Comment: It that a correct app URL `APP_URL=http://localhost`?

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze please search for the solution , i will provide you any other information you require

Comment: Is should be your base URL

Comment: @AnkurTiwari corrected but still getting the same problem

Comment: I checked url API giving 302 error check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020477/laravel-unexpected-redirects-302

Comment: In your console, all the assets url coming from your resource folder, not from public

Comment: @AnkurTiwari i dont think that will resolve the problem , my dashboard is not only arraged and showing properly, and that solution is regarding log out

Comment: Okay, But I don't know if it is against the rule of StackOverflow or not

Comment: Database credentials have been left [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56969311/revisions) of this question. Please make sure they are changed at your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to get the solution but it was very simple, I just had to copy my resources folder to `public_html`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the output of your browser console, e.g. by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I if using Chrome. I could see a lot of 404s (ressource not found) in Chrome console.

E.g.

> GET 
>     http://bhatidhruv.000webhostapp.com/resources/views/admin/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap- 
>     timepicker.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Second, is to have a look in you webserver logs. Please see the hosts help in their forum, as [seen here](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/where-is-my-error-log-hosting/65859).

Please let us know your feedback, to further help.

Comment: i also looked at many 404 error , i think there is a problem in links of images , can you just help me , i am new and have no idea , can you correct the error for me